# int not affected by Math.Round

Tags: c#, php, .net, .net-4.0, rounding

I have this piece of code at the moment: I just tryout to convert it PHP to C#

```
if (round($mounth)<="6") {
    $startYear=$year-1;
    $startMounth="-07";
    $startDay="-01";
    $endYear=$year;
    $endMounth="-06";
    $endDay="-30";
}
```

Here i tried to convert to to C# code.But i just step up to coding initially i got the error. I thought the why of .NET somehow incorrect.

```
if (Math.Round(month <= 6)
{
    string StartYear = Year-1;
}
```

Comment: Can't actually round a Boolean value...

Comment: What is month? An int? If so you should use `if (month<=6) { ... }`

Comment: @Marco int month = today.Month;

Comment: Math.Round(month <= 6) == round the result of comparing month to 6

Comment: @expert9 As a continue to our last chat in the comments in your previous question - I would suggest learning C# from books - not from others. At least not the basics. There's really no point in posting a question for every little thing you bump into (not being rude, that's just the way it is). You can find good C# books references [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477748/what-are-the-best-c-sharp-net-books).

Comment: MSDN seems to be the best C# book for me. You can begin with: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx both pages contain examples

Comment: @Eiver actually i read MSDN but difficult to understand.now reading C# dummies

Comment: @expert9 I would recommend you to read up on types. The question implies that your understanding of a typed language is lacking. Maybe google for **statically typed vs dynamically typed languages**?

Answer (score 4):

You need to round month not `(month <= 6)`

```
if(Math.Round(month) <= 6)
          {

          }
```

**Edit:** Since you mentioned that month is today.Month, it is of type int, you don't need to round it then. It should be

```
if(month <= 6)
          {

          }
```

Comment: Error corrected.I updated my answer.Can you please check my other part of the coding.. show string StartYear = Year-1; is incorrect

Comment: @expert9: we cannot write/correct all the code for you. You first have to learn the basics. Your new part is wrong because you're mixing strings and ints: in C# this is not allowed !!! `string startYear = (Year -1).ToString();`, this is the answer. But forget PHP please: C# is different, really different. Buy a book (C# for dummies?) and learn the basics

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean:

```
if(Math.Round(month) <= 6)
      {

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because month is an int (you tell me `int month = today.Month;`) you should simply use

```
if (month <= 6) 
{ 
    // ... 
}
```

Your code fails because you have wrong parenthesis and you're not rounding a float or double but a boolean. Anyway I repeat: month is an int so you don't need to round it.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one parenthesis. Use this instead:-

```
if(Math.Round(month) <= 6)
          {

          }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should round month and not the condition.

```
if (Math.Round(month) <= 6)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a great discussion about math.round.... but please use DateTime to define a point in time and TimeSpan to define a duration in time. You can compare them, add them, etc. No need to port PHP hacks to C#